# why (int*)++ move forward by 4 and (int**)++/(int***)++ move forward by 8? Should all pointer either 4 bytes or 8 bytes?

Tags: c, pointers

Please try the following code:

```
void intArrayAsPointerPrinter(int iSize){

    int * p = 0;
    int ** q = 0;
    int *** r = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < iSize; i++) {
        printf("%p %p %p\n", p,q,r);
        p++;
        q++;
        r++;
    }
}
```

Call it with size 3 and I got the following output:

```
0x0 0x0 0x0
0x4 0x8 0x8
0x8 0x10 0x10
```

Q: why (int*)++ move forward by 4 and others move forward by 8? Should all pointer either 4 bytes or 8 bytes?

Comment: `p` is a pointer to an int, so incrementing it moves forward by `sizeof(int)` which is 4 on your system. `q` is a pointer to an `int*`, so incrementing it moves forward by `sizeof(int*)` which is 8 on your system. There is no requirement that `sizeof(int) == sizeof(int*)`.

Comment: If you have learned that for any array or pointer `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is exactly equal to `p[i]`, then it makes more sense. If `p` points to the first element of an array, then `p + 1` must point to the next element of the array. And if the array is an array of `int` elements, then `p + 1` will increase by the size of `int` (which is commonly `4` these days). It's the same for `int *` elements, then the pointer is incremented by the size of `int *`.

Answer (score 6):

Advancing a pointer advances it by the size of one of things pointed.

A `int *` points to an `int`, so incrementing one advances it by the size of an `int`. Your `int` happen to be four in size.

A `int **` points to an `int *`, so incrementing one advances it by the size of an `int *`. Your `int *` happen to be eight in size.